# Clustering new points in polygon

Tags: python, cluster-computing, polygon, point

I have a polygon made of GPS coordinates, these polygon is country lets say Poland and I have 30 already existing points in that polygon made of GPS coordinates. These 30 points are not distributed evenly in that polygon and my goal is to create new 10 points in that polygon using clustering.

I have tried it for few days, I tried k-means, DBSCAN but no matter what I do It does not work. It either does not create 10 points but only 1 or it just changes one of those already existing points into new one or it creates some points but not in the polygon and in everycase there is no sign of trying to create any point in some even distributed way. So my question is pretty simple, can I even use clustering for such thing or did I just understood it wrong and what it does. I know how clustering works and what it does to a datasets but I just cant apply that to my problem.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

# Define the coordinates for the polygon
coords = [(51.20750669474411, 14.771064752102495),
          (50.3723916491531, 11.814788193533916),
          (48.50440302296322, 13.967327062741662),
          (48.534998749507885, 16.951318714046824),
          (49.58224848458308, 19.057665762026932),
          (50.43716140927117, 17.7365796749166),
          (51.166973917905295, 15.399273520798316),
          (51.20750669474411, 14.771064752102495)]
polygon = Polygon(coords)

# Define the existing points within the polygon
existing_points = [(50.17959204532467, 15.933794312781023),
                   (49.73773753981636, 13.625912823974723),
                   (49.21735566602075, 16.84855409350198),
                   (50.62311076818633, 14.563920611496346),
                   (50.11205389160936, 12.752308482828356),
                   (49.628634641977655, 18.19787451760077),
                   (49.67842445515853, 16.801569465294627),
                   (50.03339498666959, 14.48862122510739),
                   (49.447870172525306, 14.285816210548106),
                   (50.115288565936275, 12.567911717003131),
                   (50.25183321926949, 15.835340641617428),
                   (49.79213754282857, 15.495520622255166)]

# Extract the coordinates of the existing points
existing_coords = np.array([(p[0], p[1]) for p in existing_points])

# Create a scatter plot of the existing points
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.scatter(existing_coords[:, 0], existing_coords[:, 1], c='blue')

# Generate new points using k-means clustering
n_clusters = 9
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)
kmeans.fit(existing_coords)
new_coords = kmeans.cluster_centers_

# Check if the new points are within the polygon
new_points = []
for coord in new_coords:
    point = Point(coord[0], coord[1])
    if polygon.contains(point):
        new_points.append(coord)

# Add the new points to the scatter plot
ax.scatter(np.array(new_points)[:, 0], np.array(new_points)[:, 1], c='red')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image: n_clusters = 2]

[image: n_clusters = 9]

Comment: Can you show a [mcve] and also show the different things you've tried (and how it did not result in something you wanted)?

Comment: I edited my question so that you can see it, you can see that it just changes the color of the points

Comment: Thanks for providing the code, very helpful. However, I don't realy see what the issue is. Your code plots 12 points, finds 9 clusters, then plots the center of these 9 clusters. All cluster centers fall within the polygon, some centers overlap exactly with an existing point. [Here I've plotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmX4U.png) the boundary in green, the original points as large blue points, and the cluster centers in red. Could you indicate what you expect the outcome to be?

Comment: well its more like that I would need that code to create new 10 points, my goal is not to find those 1-12 cluster, but to create 10 new points, but I need them to be distributed evenly, maybe I am jsut doing totally different thing.

Comment: Then perhaps it's better to clearify in your question what you want exactly, maybe even add a graph of what you want the end result to look like (with points added in e.g. Paint), because currently your question is unclear, and the code is doing what you're asking it to. When you say "distributed evenly" do you mean like a grid?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I will start a new question with exactly what I want to achieve.